# How to get the point in time of (last) vertical retrace under Python?

Tags: python, pygame, flip

I am using Pygame to pageflip different stimuli on the screen. The problem is that pygame's flip function, although syncing the flip to the vertical retrace, does not tell me when the retrace was.
Does anyone know of a way to get this information (preferably platform independent) in Python?

Regards,
fladd

Comment: In general, you can't, particularly if you've got triple-buffering going on.  Anyhow, this isn't a Python question, it's an OS API question with a thin Python binding on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just poll for the time immediately after the flip call, if that one syncs to the vertical retrace.